# Python:Pandas dataframe object unable to convert to string

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to get the string "A" instead of object "A"

```
>>> comp
                                                                      1
0                                                                      
marketCapitalization                                            27879.5
name                                           Agilent Technologies Inc
exchange                                  NEW YORK STOCK EXCHANGE, INC.
country                                                              US
weburl                                         https://www.agilent.com/
ipo                                                          1999-11-18
phone                                                       14083458886
currency                                                            USD
logo                  https://static.finnhub.io/logo/5f1f8412-80eb-1...
ticker                                                                A
marketCapitalization                                            27879.5
finnhubIndustry                          Life Sciences Tools & Services
shareOutstanding                                                308.777
>>> comp.loc['ticker']
1    A
Name: ticker, dtype: object
```

I am trying `comp.loc['ticker'].astype(str)` but still return an object. I need it to show "A" only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to select the first element with `.iloc[0]`:

```
comp.loc['ticker'].iloc[0]
```